# cookie set with php not available after js redirect and new php script checks with isset

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

So this is my first time using cookies and i'm having some trouble setting them. I think i'm doing everything correctly (but you know how programming can be). anyways I am creating a login system that will through a `jquery.ajax` call in `validateLogin.js`, to one php script (autologin.php), check if a user and their password are in a database by way of a function in another script (login.php), in `login.php` if the user exists and the password is the same the cookie is set and some json data is returned to `autologin.php` which then returns some more json data to the original `jquery.ajax` methods `success` function. the `success` function will then redirect to `userarea.html`, where a js function will automatically load the user data so it is available for use. this is done with another `ajax` call in `loaduserdata.js` which calls to `loaduserdata.php` which checks `isset($_COOKIE['user']`, and then returns some json data depending on what happens. however the `isset($_COOKIE['user']` fails and i'm not getting any errors in the console or in any of the logs (php, mysql, apache). So i'm really stumped. here is my code:

`validateLogin.js`

```
function validateLogin(){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginform").submit(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./php/autologin.php",
        data: {
          'login': $("#login").val(), 
          'password': $("#password").val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
          if(data.status == "success"){
            alert(data.message);
            window.location = "./userarea.html";
          } else if (data.status == "error"){
            alert(data.message);
          }
        },
        error:function(thrownError){
          console.log(thrownError);
        }
      }); 
      return false;
    });

  });
}
```

`autologin.php`

```
<?php

include './login.php';
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$loginattempt = login($login, $password);
$loginattemptdata = json_decode($loginattempt);
if ($loginattemptdata->{'status'} === "success") {
  echo json_encode(array('status' => "success", 'user' => $loginattemptdata->{"user"}, 'message' => "Login Successful!"));
  die();
} else {
  echo json_encode(array('status' => "error", 'error' => "loginfailure", 'message' => $loginattemptdata->{"message"}));
  die();
}
?>
```

`login.php`

```
<?php
include './connect_to_mysql.php';

function login($log, $pass) {
  $link = connect_to_mysql();
  $linkdata = json_decode($link);
  if ($linkdata->{'status'} === "success") {
    $sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE login='$log' AND password='$pass'") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($sqlquery) == 1) {
      setcookie("user", $log, 86400, '/', 'localhost');
      return json_encode(array('status' => "success", 'message' => "Login Successful.", 'user' => $log));
      die();
    } else {
      return json_encode(array('status' => "error", 'error' => "loginfailure", 'message' => mysql_error()));
      die();
    }
  } else {
    return json_encode(array('status' => "error", 'error' => "connectionerror", 'message' => $linkdata->{'message'}));
    die();
  }
}

?>
```

`loaduserdata.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"./php/loaduserdata.php",
    success:function(data){
      if(data.status === "success"){
        alert(data.status);
        alert(data.user);
      } else if (data.status === "error"){
        alert(data.status);
        alert(data.message);
        window.location = "./index.html";
      }
    },
    error:function(thrownError){
      console.log(thrownError);
    }
  });
});
```

`loaduserdata.php`

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
  $user = $_COOKIE['user'];
  echo json_encode(array('status' => "success", 'message' => $user));
  die();
} else {
  echo json_encode(array('status' => "error", 'message' => "Please login before continuing."));
  die();
}
?>
```

from what i've read you need to either refresh or redirect after setting a cookie for it to be available to a new script, which i believe is what i am doing. any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on a client side cookie for login status is a bad idea. Imagine what happens if the user crafts his own cookie with a random (valid) username? He will have gained access to your system without need for a password.

Have you considered switching to a $_SESSION-based authentication procedure?

The concept is that every visitor is assigned a unique ID (the session ID) which is stored as a cookie client side. When the visitor loads a page, the sessid cookie is passed along and php loads it from a session storage (most likely a file in /tmp/ if you haven't configured sessions yet). This file is reflected with the $_SESSION variable, in which you can save data that is only accessible to that corresponding session ID. Thus, usernames or login status is handled server-side and never client side.

```
<?php
# login.php
include './connect_to_mysql.php';

function login($log, $pass) {
  $link = connect_to_mysql();
  $linkdata = json_decode($link);
  if ($linkdata->{'status'} === "success") {
    $sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE login='$log' AND password='$pass'") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($sqlquery) == 1) {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['user'] = $log;
      return json_encode(array('status' => "success", 'message' => "Login Successful.", 'user' => $log));
    } else {
      return json_encode(array('status' => "error", 'error' => "loginfailure", 'message' => mysql_error()));
    }
  } else {
    return json_encode(array('status' => "error", 'error' => "connectionerror", 'message' => $linkdata->{'message'}));
  }
}
?>
```

Changes: (1) drop the die() after return. They are never executed. (2) save to session via session_start() and $_SESSION['user'] = $log; instead of using your own cookies.

```
<?php
# loaduserdata.php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
  $user = $_SESSION['user'];
  echo json_encode(array('status' => "success", 'message' => $user));
  die();
} else {
  echo json_encode(array('status' => "error", 'message' => "Please login before continuing."));
  die();
}
?>
```

Changes: use session_start() and $_SESSION['user'] rather than relying on client side cookies.

Comment: i hadn't but i'll look into it, is it very difficult?

Comment: In short: (1) in login.php you do ''$_SESSION['user'] = $log;'' rather than ''setcookie''. (2) in loaduserdata.php you do ''if(isset($_SESSION['user']))''. This way, the login status/username is not saved client-side but server-side. At the top of every php script you have to do ''session_start();'' -- which will ensure that the user's session is recognized.